# NativeScript duplicate kotlin class on `ns run android`

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've been working on an application that I got from a leaving colleague and I am new to NativeScript.

When trying to run an app on an Android emulator using the `ns run android` command I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

I've tried the following:

- update NativeScript
- updating all the dependencies
- checking out an older commit do be sure this isn't due to my last commits
- trying this on different machines (MacOs and Ubuntu)
- adding different lines of code to the `platforms/android/build.gradle` file following other posts on this matter...

The `ns run ios` works fine, so I'm guessing this is something Java/Android related. Any help would be highly appreciated.

My `package.json` file if this can help:

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "version": "7.0.1",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@finanzritter/nativescript-share-file": "^2.0.1",
    "@nativescript-community/sentry": "^4.6.12",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-canvas": "^4.0.50",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-collectionview": "^4.0.29",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-image": "4.3.6",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-bottom-navigation": "^7.0.24",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-core": "^7.0.24",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-material-tabs": "^7.0.24",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-pager": "^13.0.2",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-pulltorefresh": "^2.5.3",
    "@nativescript-community/ui-webview": "^1.4.4",
    "@nativescript-community/universal-links": "^2.0.7",
    "@nativescript/background-http": "^6.0.0",
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.15",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.5.9",
    "@nativescript/email": "^2.0.5",
    "@nativescript/firebase-analytics": "^3.1.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase-core": "^3.1.0",
    "@nativescript/firebase-messaging": "^3.1.0",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/imagepicker": "^1.0.9",
    "@nativescript/localize": "^5.0.2",
    "@nativescript/social-share": "^2.0.1",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^4.1.2",
    "nativescript-imagecropper": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-universal-links": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "^8.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.1.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.9.3",
    "nativescript-vue-multi-drawer": "^0.0.4",
    "nativescript-websockets": "^1.5.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.6.2",
    "@nativescript/ios": "~8.6.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.18",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "-",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

[Update 2024-02-01]
In the meantime I've been able to reduce the culprite to 2 dependencies:

- "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.3.1"
- "@nativescript/background-http": "^6.0.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer here in case it can help others:

I've had to add the following line in the `App_Resources/Android/gradle.properties` (in my case I needed to create it first):

```
useKotlin=true
```

and add the following in the `App_Resources/Android/before-plugins.gradle` file:

```
project.ext {
  kotlinVersion = "1.9.10"
}
```

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/plugins/issues/569#issuecomment-1920893513)

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar issue for Ionic and React Native, and tried to apply the same fix to my NativeScript project. It seems like it worked. I'm not sure how good and future-proof the solution is, I would appreciate a comment from others, but it got me over the bump.
Add this to your app.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  constraints {
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
          because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
      }
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
          because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
      }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with NativeScript. The answer was given to me on the GitHub repo: https://github.com/NativeScript/plugins/issues/569#issuecomment-1921843068